# Visual Studio: some projects in solution don't generate .exe files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio C++ solution with 3 projects: one contains all classes and their definition, and generates .lib file (static library). Other two projects conatin main functions: one for running the application and one for testing (via googletest). They both should generate .exe files, as it's specified in Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Configuration Type, but they both don't actually generate .exe files. Solution builds without errors. What's a problem?

Comment: What is the output directory of the one project failing to generate the exe file?

Comment: Not a lot of possible failure modes here.  Are you looking in the right place for the .exe?  It goes into the solution directory, not the project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `exe` in `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Output File`.